# application crash when in ad-hoc mode throw Test-flight - worked just fine

Tags: iphone, objective-c, crash, adhoc, crash-reports

i have this application im building and my costumer gets it throw test flight in the last 3 weeks and every thing was great.. until today. i just finished working on the application and send it to him as usual. but its was crash, when i tried to install it, it was crash for me too.

when im running the application throw xcode on my device its working perfectly.
so i downloaded the crash log from the device - can someone please help me figure it out.

```
Incident Identifier: 56C4BF08-4F22-4501-957D-F8C9920B99D0
CrashReporter Key:   463d6c316ad4d18e634919c404611f9dcda0565b
Hardware Model:      iPhone3,1
Process:         Alkolombre [22095]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/E8FB2CA8-85EC-47D0-8891-3FA4A9762151/Alkolombre.app/Alkolombre
Identifier:      Alkolombre
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2012-04-08 19:39:20.195 +0300
OS Version:      iPhone OS 5.1 (9B176)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x00000000, 0x00000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x34e8a88f __exceptionPreprocess + 163
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x362b1259 objc_exception_throw + 33
2   CoreFoundation                  0x34e8a789 +[NSException raise:format:] + 1
3   CoreFoundation                  0x34e8a7ab +[NSException raise:format:] + 35
4   Foundation                      0x30cae05f -[NSURL(NSURL) initFileURLWithPath:] + 79
5   Foundation                      0x30cadffb +[NSURL(NSURL) fileURLWithPath:] + 43
6   Alkolombre                      0x00020047 -[AlarmManager initialize] (AlarmManager.m:73)
7   Alkolombre                      0x0001728f -[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] (AppDelegate.m:55)
8   UIKit                           0x31ee0e53 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForURL:payload:suspended:] + 1183
9   UIKit                           0x31eda985 -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 409
10  UIKit                           0x31ea8c6b -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 1011
11  UIKit                           0x31ea870f -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 55
12  UIKit                           0x31ea80e3 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 5827
13  GraphicsServices                0x360dd22b PurpleEventCallback + 883
14  CoreFoundation                  0x34e5e523 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 39
15  CoreFoundation                  0x34e5e4c5 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 141
16  CoreFoundation                  0x34e5d313 __CFRunLoopRun + 1371
17  CoreFoundation                  0x34de04a5 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 301
18  CoreFoundation                  0x34de036d CFRunLoopRunInMode + 105
19  UIKit                           0x31ed9a13 -[UIApplication _run] + 551
20  UIKit                           0x31ed6e7d UIApplicationMain + 1081
21  Alkolombre                      0x00016f37 main (main.m:16)
22  Alkolombre                      0x000169d0 0x15000 + 6608


Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x34c7e32c __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x36b7a208 pthread_kill + 48
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x36b73298 abort + 88
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x3083ff64 abort_message + 40
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x3083d346 _ZL17default_terminatev + 18
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x362b1350 _objc_terminate + 140
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x3083d3be _ZL19safe_handler_callerPFvvE + 70
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x3083d44a std::terminate() + 14
8   libc++abi.dylib                 0x3083e81e __cxa_rethrow + 82
9   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x362b12a2 objc_exception_rethrow + 6
10  CoreFoundation                  0x34de0506 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 398
11  CoreFoundation                  0x34de0366 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 98
12  UIKit                           0x31ed9a0c -[UIApplication _run] + 544
13  UIKit                           0x31ed6e76 UIApplicationMain + 1074
14  Alkolombre                      0x00016f30 main (main.m:16)
15  Alkolombre                      0x000169c8 0x15000 + 6600

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x34c6e3a8 kevent + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x30ebbea4 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 708
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x30ebbbc2 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 30

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x34c7ecd4 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x36b35f36 _pthread_wqthread + 610
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x36b35cc8 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x34c7ecd4 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x36b35f36 _pthread_wqthread + 610
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x36b35cc8 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 4 name:  WebThread
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x34c7e0d8 __psynch_mutexwait + 24
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x36b2f674 pthread_mutex_lock + 376
2   WebCore                         0x36bbfa2c _ZL17_WebTryThreadLockb + 208
3   WebCore                         0x36bbfd30 _ZL14WebRunLoopLockP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 24
4   CoreFoundation                  0x34e5eb14 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 12
5   CoreFoundation                  0x34e5cd50 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 252
6   CoreFoundation                  0x34e5d16a __CFRunLoopRun + 946
7   CoreFoundation                  0x34de049e CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 294
8   CoreFoundation                  0x34de0366 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 98
9   WebCore                         0x36c630f0 _ZL12RunWebThreadPv + 396
10  libsystem_c.dylib               0x36b3b72e _pthread_start + 314
11  libsystem_c.dylib               0x36b3b5e8 thread_start + 0

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State:
    r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000001      r3: 0x00000000
    r4: 0x00000006    r5: 0x3f586d98      r6: 0x00000002      r7: 0x2fe13a5c
    r8: 0x00192320    r9: 0x30840a4a     r10: 0x00000000     r11: 0x0018c560
    ip: 0x00000148    sp: 0x2fe13a50      lr: 0x36b7a20f      pc: 0x34c7e32c
  cpsr: 0x000f0010

Binary Images:
   0x15000 -    0x35fff +Alkolombre armv7  <b270034dc4c93b4398c2b352cf391ef2> /var/mobile/Applications/E8FB2CA8-85EC-47D0-8891-3FA4A9762151/Alkolombre.app/Alkolombre
0x2fe14000 - 0x2fe35fff  dyld armv7  <4a817f3e0def30d5ae2032157d889c1d> /usr/lib/dyld
0x300f9000 - 0x300fdfff  IOMobileFramebuffer armv7  <42dbc26828e934acabb4f3b0a35d8250> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/IOMobileFramebuffer
0x300fe000 - 0x300fefff  liblangid.dylib armv7  <644ff4bcfbf337b5b5859e3f0fc0a9a8> /usr/lib/liblangid.dylib
0x3015e000 - 0x306a2fff  FaceCoreLight armv7  <f326d88709683520b251dc53cb847c11> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FaceCoreLight.framework/FaceCoreLight
0x306a3000 - 0x30722fff  libsqlite3.dylib armv7  <bf01f5ed47b033d8bde30d735ff44416> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x3074a000 - 0x30822fff  vImage armv7  <caf3648be2933384b6aa1ae7408ab4f0> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vImage.framework/vImage
0x30839000 - 0x30840fff  libc++abi.dylib armv7  <bab4dcbfc5943d3fbb637342d35e8045> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
0x30841000 - 0x30892fff  CoreText armv7  <5bfac4ee88d03d5b87a1f105abb7756c> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
0x30924000 - 0x30924fff  libkeymgr.dylib armv7  <ebd2dddf55d83cf48a18913968775960> /usr/lib/system/libkeymgr.dylib
0x30925000 - 0x30995fff  CoreImage armv7  <86ac6f5a267637b6b7f8a831dfc7c64b> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreImage.framework/CoreImage
0x309cb000 - 0x30a07fff  iCalendar armv7  <f2836083051132d3aa40ad82d7f73aea> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/iCalendar.framework/iCalendar
0x30a08000 - 0x30a13fff  AccountSettings armv7  <373e59421d983c93931cfbad87b1ae35> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AccountSettings.framework/AccountSettings
0x30a14000 - 0x30a14fff  Accelerate armv7  <55b24cf91a8b3532bde6733c96f14c08> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x30a38000 - 0x30a81fff  libc++.1.dylib armv7  <5b690e5dd5a43a7fb166ade9fe58a7a4> /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
0x30a82000 - 0x30a85fff  libmacho.dylib armv7  <e52b77623bd031bc807e77029566c777> /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
0x30a86000 - 0x30b0cfff  CoreMotion armv7  <6a9355d5a8e238b5b8f193605d509e15> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMotion.framework/CoreMotion
0x30b46000 - 0x30b47fff  DataMigration armv7  <d77f0e8f39ee37f5a2ac713a3fd9e693> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataMigration.framework/DataMigration
0x30b5a000 - 0x30b9afff  libGLImage.dylib armv7  <40448706190031f6b0d9636cc11ee81d> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib
0x30b9b000 - 0x30b9cfff  libsystem_blocks.dylib armv7  <9fdc27af7350323bbc7d98e14e027907> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
0x30bb5000 - 0x30bd4fff  libSystem.B.dylib armv7  <0c55744b6f7335eebba4ca2c3d10b43c> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x30bd5000 - 0x30c0dfff  VideoToolbox armv7  <9f25f38d1cd13a1daff99cfde8884410> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox
0x30c94000 - 0x30c9bfff  StoreKit armv7  <1bc0c05f99a8309d90476b42263e3487> /System/Library/Frameworks/StoreKit.framework/StoreKit
0x30c9c000 - 0x30e1afff  Foundation armv7  <c40ddb073142315bb4ebb214343d0b7f> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x30e26000 - 0x30e27fff  libdyld.dylib armv7  <977b0ad6f2f433108b4a0324a57cd2ab> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
0x30e28000 - 0x30e3dfff  libresolv.9.dylib armv7  <66f7557fa4b43979b186e00271839fdb> /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
0x30e3e000 - 0x30e63fff  OpenCL armv7  <ec915bfc3f7633dda61b5fc87459119b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/OpenCL.framework/OpenCL
0x30ea8000 - 0x30eaefff  MobileIcons armv7  <ed1b46f917903c9b9baaa2be4392dafe> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileIcons.framework/MobileIcons
0x30eaf000 - 0x30ec5fff  libdispatch.dylib armv7  <9ecfaef4110a3bf9a92d12f0fe8d1d78> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
0x30ec6000 - 0x30ed0fff  libbz2.1.0.dylib armv7  <40e4045fb79e382b8833707746cf28b1> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
0x30ed7000 - 0x30edcfff  ApplePushService armv7  <f424c0340de637c08bbeb4f3bd8c6eaf> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ApplePushService.framework/ApplePushService
0x30f1c000 - 0x30f2dfff  DataAccessExpress armv7  <e6144ba265da3bb7b9a263aa1a29b054> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccessExpress.framework/DataAccessExpress
0x30f2e000 - 0x30f2efff  vecLib armv7  <a2cfe25e77aa36bfb4a30b2d0d2dd465> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x30f34000 - 0x30f71fff  FTServices armv7  <28ed78e01a77388cb4c0f2f6ec33482c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FTServices.framework/FTServices
0x30f91000 - 0x31005fff  MediaControlSender armv7  <87315c54b2293ab589950341ff91b45d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaControlSender.framework/MediaControlSender
0x31006000 - 0x31042fff  AppSupport armv7  <311eac85b2a433a884dacba77217b49e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x311dd000 - 0x31201fff  PrintKit armv7  <08509c7bc915358b953de6f5cbef5c56> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PrintKit.framework/PrintKit
0x31205000 - 0x31239fff  MIME armv7  <d30292ea8f7e360fa5f5d5b1b62b602d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MIME.framework/MIME
0x31261000 - 0x31265fff  libGFXShared.dylib armv7  <998fccc16cf735dbb62324202995e193> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib
0x31270000 - 0x31316fff  AddressBookUI armv7  <da424fecc66e3628ab03378ae80b38fc> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBookUI.framework/AddressBookUI
0x3133b000 - 0x31379fff  IOKit armv7  <fcda71d29d6136dfbd84c1725f4998e5> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x313e4000 - 0x313e5fff  libdnsinfo.dylib armv7  <9aede8d6579d3430ac39ae5f95cce498> /usr/lib/system/libdnsinfo.dylib
0x314e3000 - 0x314eafff  AssetsLibraryServices armv7  <0703f561f9a038b6850d6e93bba7e5f4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices
0x314eb000 - 0x314ecfff  libremovefile.dylib armv7  <402f8956975d3b6fb86ab9b31a43242c> /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
0x31552000 - 0x3159cfff  libvDSP.dylib armv7  <441b42aca07b3da39feab25f8349918f> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x315cf000 - 0x3162cfff  StoreServices armv7  <628fbbc73ed93730962c53bfbfde6794> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/StoreServices.framework/StoreServices
0x31818000 - 0x3195dfff  CoreGraphics armv7  <903545b89a7f311d95100ac7d1d44709> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x31983000 - 0x31992fff  GenerationalStorage armv7  <d84c3fd0e7bd36e78c256f2f4c5a4e91> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GenerationalStorage.framework/GenerationalStorage
0x31993000 - 0x31a49fff  AVFoundation armv7  <35cb7a0eb1dc3554a777c1cc11cb0415> /System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/AVFoundation
0x31a98000 - 0x31af0fff  CoreAudio armv7  <be335e8eb6f93594b028a6ddd503a183> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
0x31af1000 - 0x31afdfff  libCRFSuite.dylib armv7  <bdb2b4d1a78c39c1ba60d791207aed2a> /usr/lib/libCRFSuite.dylib
0x31b04000 - 0x31b0afff  liblaunch.dylib armv7  <aa2bcba6fc7a36a191958fef2e995475> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
0x31b0b000 - 0x31b0ffff  IOSurface armv7  <6ae77a40f8e93f28bc466ca93f5675d4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
0x31b26000 - 0x31b49fff  Bom armv7  <c3435ecd2e5839f89de51edad0e1bb00> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Bom
0x31c17000 - 0x31c1bfff  AggregateDictionary armv7  <3a3a33f3a05538988c6e2bb363dc46a8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/AggregateDictionary
0x31c2e000 - 0x31c3bfff  libbsm.0.dylib armv7  <750a0de73a733019a77144b805d4d2f8> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
0x31e24000 - 0x31e30fff  libz.1.dylib armv7  <36ce86a3dc8c344596c8c325615f374b> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
0x31e7d000 - 0x31e8efff  libxpc.dylib armv7  <ccf25b1e49ce3b2fa58d8c8546755505> /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib
0x31ea1000 - 0x31ea4fff  NetworkStatistics armv7  <7848d8ebad99367cb4f7f4e3fe88e5d6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/NetworkStatistics.framework/NetworkStatistics
0x31ea5000 - 0x32347fff  UIKit armv7  <d72bcc68e76a3a55a963590cdcffe8cd> /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
0x32351000 - 0x324f7fff  CoreData armv7  <b0215b6d4d143859a2b313ecade095ec> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/CoreData
0x32574000 - 0x327a1fff  MediaToolbox armv7  <ec9bc89489763c6c93f86c5c490b2d69> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaToolbox.framework/MediaToolbox
0x32b41000 - 0x32b45fff  CertUI armv7  <f503892ef60e36108d28d8f9d6144d2a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CertUI.framework/CertUI
0x32b6c000 - 0x32b7bfff  OpenGLES armv7  <e80acc691001301e96101bb89d940033> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
0x32b7c000 - 0x32b86fff  libvMisc.dylib armv7  <e8248c797b9b363594bb652ddf7ce16d> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvMisc.dylib
0x32b93000 - 0x32bf7fff  MessageUI armv7  <b74d79ea691a35ada276f063b7217a20> /System/Library/Frameworks/MessageUI.framework/MessageUI
0x33416000 - 0x33455fff  QuickLook armv7  <802b1092542a3017a0380632502610d4> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuickLook.framework/QuickLook
0x33456000 - 0x3345afff  libcache.dylib armv7  <d6a7436ed8dc33d795c9b42baf864882> /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
0x33461000 - 0x33531fff  WebKit armv7  <6ff2796c2f933050ac6ecdee9fc6a216> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKit
0x3360d000 - 0x33659fff  CoreTelephony armv7  <e8eb52ca5fe33c7488a33efd222e7804> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
0x3367b000 - 0x336c3fff  CoreMedia armv7  <eb1f503312be3c93b07b2d0d25177000> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia
0x33768000 - 0x33856fff  libiconv.2.dylib armv7  <2cfefe2ad1d335dd9549562910e7a2e2> /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
0x33857000 - 0x3392efff  CFNetwork armv7  <765a472c824830eea91b8f02d12867e4> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x33a67000 - 0x33aa3fff  IMFoundation armv7  <77bb4365a65b32a49523b03da0340dbc> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IMCore.framework/Frameworks/IMFoundation.framework/IMFoundation
0x33aa4000 - 0x33bc9fff  JavaScriptCore armv7  <2ffc6c87b94434288366bd53765ee267> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
0x33c39000 - 0x33c62fff  AppleAccount armv7  <2ba44023410231fcb3f72f762ea3ce6e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleAccount.framework/AppleAccount
0x33c7c000 - 0x33c88fff  CoreVideo armv7  <364fa32d513f3c11b50970120545f1a8> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
0x33df0000 - 0x33e06fff  DictionaryServices armv7  <6ed2e967136f37d4a4b9b318d6c43b83> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DictionaryServices.framework/DictionaryServices
0x3419b000 - 0x3445cfff  libLAPACK.dylib armv7  <0e94e9a7e7a334649afaccae0f1215a2> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
0x3445d000 - 0x34473fff  libmis.dylib armv7  <258bc92be5823b239b4412dd42cb4807> /usr/lib/libmis.dylib
0x34495000 - 0x344e6fff  libstdc++.6.dylib armv7  <c352af5a742e3c7a8d4d7e5f6f454793> /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
0x344e7000 - 0x3451efff  Security armv7  <eea56f71fde83c2981f9281dc7823725> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x34538000 - 0x34568fff  ContentIndex armv7  <7a64670bb2ff3ee39ddee1dc1c72f92d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ContentIndex.framework/ContentIndex
0x345cd000 - 0x34608fff  libCGFreetype.A.dylib armv7  <55941c96cf1f3b048e72a148c4496c16> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCGFreetype.A.dylib
0x34628000 - 0x3462dfff  libcopyfile.dylib armv7  <52e874396c393ed29099789ce702cfe2> /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
0x34708000 - 0x3470efff  MobileKeyBag armv7  <e1f06241ef0e3f0aae00f15df572077e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileKeyBag.framework/MobileKeyBag
0x34807000 - 0x34851fff  ManagedConfiguration armv7  <5e0a131bbfec305ea01f9e01f486da63> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ManagedConfiguration.framework/ManagedConfiguration
0x34852000 - 0x3487efff  libtidy.A.dylib armv7  <3aacc5b650e037c086a8ff6657d154bf> /usr/lib/libtidy.A.dylib
0x3487f000 - 0x34888fff  libMobileGestalt.dylib armv7  <4a15e845dc6f3a4a980de66c1cc44c42> /usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib
0x349c1000 - 0x349d8fff  WebBookmarks armv7  <bd20a05587783a8e9596eef1d3615ea7> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebBookmarks.framework/WebBookmarks
0x349d9000 - 0x349f1fff  Notes armv7  <724966ed5cd4395cb70f9c996b123f53> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Notes.framework/Notes
0x349f2000 - 0x34a75fff  MapKit armv7  <e39706ac199134a497954e1f1d6d7245> /System/Library/Frameworks/MapKit.framework/MapKit
0x34a84000 - 0x34a98fff  PersistentConnection armv7  <65682d21486836a3aa3e17b9461e7b3a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PersistentConnection.framework/PersistentConnection
0x34aa3000 - 0x34ad8fff  DataAccess armv7  <89fd0c22338b37538cf61803a0bca9e2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccess.framework/DataAccess
0x34adc000 - 0x34b55fff  ProofReader armv7  <6db611d8df6530d480f97a40bc519f70> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProofReader.framework/ProofReader
0x34c63000 - 0x34c66fff  CaptiveNetwork armv7  <f5cc4b97ce9432da9426f12621453325> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CaptiveNetwork.framework/CaptiveNetwork
0x34c6d000 - 0x34c83fff  libsystem_kernel.dylib armv7  <7ac5560851ce3cb3981068092074b409> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
0x34dd1000 - 0x34ee8fff  CoreFoundation armv7  <6d450fe923d7387f8b01845e0edd713d> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x3506c000 - 0x350b1fff  GeoServices armv7  <a26be2e76e8730ab91a16502aba376be> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GeoServices.framework/GeoServices
0x351fd000 - 0x35232fff  SystemConfiguration armv7  <4464a4e3bb3f32f7abaa35ebf31fda49> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x35233000 - 0x3537cfff  libicucore.A.dylib armv7  <b70646b63f1f3b33896dd8cb91b8dab1> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x35384000 - 0x353cdfff  AddressBook armv7  <b17a2962e9043e0385c3c2c652155f2b> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook
0x356d3000 - 0x356d9fff  liblockdown.dylib armv7  <9e45ce468a6f31e5b8263f2c224aa800> /usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib
0x356da000 - 0x35897fff  ImageIO armv7  <02e3578171fa3b6a969b244275fd2bab> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x358c2000 - 0x358c4fff  MobileInstallation armv7  <215d93dbb0f63cbf828f9126eb7b5349> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileInstallation.framework/MobileInstallation
0x358d2000 - 0x35928fff  GMM armv7  <6b2f7e1aa6be3d69b4c4cf54ed960602> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GMM.framework/GMM
0x35929000 - 0x3594cfff  MobileSync armv7  <e42604c550283f4aa517ae8f108b340f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileSync.framework/MobileSync
0x3599a000 - 0x359e8fff  CoreLocation armv7  <44550ebedf23334d85441d9743b74e03> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation
0x359f2000 - 0x35aa0fff  Message armv7  <b8221d43401d315fb84398b7aa570fc1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Message.framework/Message
0x35ba5000 - 0x35ba8fff  libsystem_network.dylib armv7  <356cb66612e836968ef24e6e5c3364cc> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
0x35d61000 - 0x35f45fff  AudioToolbox armv7  <c91e27850452330ea804db6408840fd2> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
0x35f46000 - 0x35f46fff  libunwind.dylib armv7  <e0a73a57795f3e1698a52ebe6fc07005> /usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib
0x36084000 - 0x3608afff  libnotify.dylib armv7  <9406297de3e43742887890662a87ab53> /usr/lib/system/libnotify.dylib
0x360bf000 - 0x360cefff  MobileDeviceLink armv7  <70ac33720f513f0f97ea2279260678ca> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDeviceLink.framework/MobileDeviceLink
0x360cf000 - 0x360d7fff  ProtocolBuffer armv7  <0e846afacf823d2b8c029cc3010a8253> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProtocolBuffer.framework/ProtocolBuffer
0x360d8000 - 0x360e2fff  GraphicsServices armv7  <e21a6e61bdd136b6805a9e3abe2e3d1f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x360e3000 - 0x360eafff  MailServices armv7  <ab2388ce733e38b7a261273a401bbbf1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MailServices.framework/MailServices
0x360f8000 - 0x3610efff  EAP8021X armv7  <fffe86a22bc434a6ae84f23bfecef9d6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/EAP8021X.framework/EAP8021X
0x36115000 - 0x361d7fff  Celestial armv7  <2a59586b0ae937c3b25fe526924aa885> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Celestial.framework/Celestial
0x362a2000 - 0x362a6fff  libAccessibility.dylib armv7  <9a17d07b5a3b38cfafdf16f78c99b572> /usr/lib/libAccessibility.dylib
0x362a8000 - 0x3636efff  libobjc.A.dylib armv7  <90014d1bc583366d85622e43097df416> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x3636f000 - 0x3636ffff  libgcc_s.1.dylib armv7  <eb82984fa36c329387aa518aa5205f3d> /usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib
0x3638a000 - 0x3638dfff  ActorKit armv7  <434c756a6b053f4ba3c954cfccddbf59> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ActorKit.framework/ActorKit
0x3641c000 - 0x36421fff  CrashReporterSupport armv7  <2bb524b3bb3c3eb2932ce13b655b7c7c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CrashReporterSupport.framework/CrashReporterSupport
0x36523000 - 0x36543fff  libxslt.1.dylib armv7  <39348471007e39dab80af68b08390456> /usr/lib/libxslt.1.dylib
0x366a7000 - 0x366c4fff  libsystem_info.dylib armv7  <50863bcbf478323e96a8e5b1a83ea6f9> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
0x366c5000 - 0x366d4fff  SpringBoardServices armv7  <ca5b10014b473d2eaec5c48d89ee1b54> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
0x36715000 - 0x36715fff  libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib armv7  <a80aaa9989483ce3a496a061fd1e9e0a> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib
0x36843000 - 0x36844fff  CoreSurface armv7  <7850befd26b630f183ee326aaadd7b34> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSurface.framework/CoreSurface
0x36932000 - 0x36935fff  libcompiler_rt.dylib armv7  <b2c05d8601c13be884097192dca4e187> /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib
0x36939000 - 0x36951fff  iAd armv7  <9e9184ed0077317a97b879c3df950316> /System/Library/Frameworks/iAd.framework/iAd
0x3696f000 - 0x36a60fff  QuartzCore armv7  <a2afbe6483683d05ad51b106f98776e2> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x36ae5000 - 0x36ae6fff  libsystem_sandbox.dylib armv7  <66e985f3eea03ef08afb7cf4c153f76e> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
0x36b28000 - 0x36b2cfff  FTClientServices armv7  <21de970d7ebb3e7fb502a0a5451b0806> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FTClientServices.framework/FTClientServices
0x36b2d000 - 0x36bb9fff  libsystem_c.dylib armv7  <f859ce1ad1773f0ba98d7c6e135b7697> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
0x36bba000 - 0x37378fff  WebCore armv7  <814351ff217e3425a8e532c2e2251f73> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore
0x3772c000 - 0x37745fff  libRIP.A.dylib armv7  <1828cddc5dd93c61afbefb59587d7f8a> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libRIP.A.dylib
0x37746000 - 0x3774afff  Marco armv7  <8dea3e558fe534ff868fc92e215ce53b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Marco.framework/Marco
0x37787000 - 0x37831fff  libBLAS.dylib armv7  <bf822cc1a3243ae7b104cf73ca22d352> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
0x37848000 - 0x3788bfff  libcommonCrypto.dylib armv7  <95b49daf4cf038b6bea8010bba3a1e26> /usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib
0x378b6000 - 0x37963fff  libxml2.2.dylib armv7  <58d47f064e0232119f4b838ad659f9c1> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
0x379a3000 - 0x379abfff  MobileWiFi armv7  <b76c3e9fb78234c392058250d4620e72> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileWiFi.framework/MobileWiFi
0x379ae000 - 0x379b3fff  libsystem_dnssd.dylib armv7  <27bb5462450732e380f5a2c170546e93> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
0x37a57000 - 0x37a9bfff  MobileCoreServices armv7  <757226927a873d5492be721908077b48> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x37b12000 - 0x37b75fff  IMCore armv7  <6e26e99b9b5f3829a8486ffd8c64f0d2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IMCore.framework/IMCore
0x37b90000 - 0x37c29fff  EventKit armv7  <d67aa1508ee7306b8e2a45c76ffddff0> /System/Library/Frameworks/EventKit.framework/EventKit
0x37cea000 - 0x37cecfff  libCoreVMClient.dylib armv7  <d4d4aa3090c83e87bcb15ed00b93fd5c> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreVMClient.dylib
0x37d07000 - 0x37d0afff  CoreTime armv7  <a398de5ba1e43a11b7008e9bb5a7f6fe> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreTime.framework/CoreTime
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it is throwing an exception from `NSURL fileUrlWithPath`, which is called from your app delegate. If you look at the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for that method, they list a few conditions that have to be met for the call to succeed: the path has to be valid and not nil. Maybe that path doesnt exist on your customer's device. You should check for the conditions I mentioned before calling the method.

Comment: Thank you very much, your answer was very helpful ! and i've learned a lor from you !